# mysql: SELECT * FROM vs SELECT column_name FROM has different result

Tags: mysql

Why does

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE col1 = a_value`

Return a different outcome

`SELECT col2 FROM table_name WHERE col1 = a_value`

The first one returns the row of the data I'm looking for but the second one says no results where found for the query. Shouldn't it return the same data but just the specific column that I'm looking for ?

Comment: Both queries should return the same number of rows.  Something else is going on.

Comment: The only difference between those queries would be the number of columns returned; the number of rows would be identical. Therefore, you cannot be running the query with the same value for `a_value`.

Comment: Must return same number of Row.... Where are you running these two query?

Comment: How does the table look like? Please show the queries you entered exactly.

Comment: Can you provide an example to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Post the table structure or it would be impossible to guess

Comment: Post a bug report at mysql with your table structure, data and version of MySQL.

Comment: In a simple test I can't reproduce the problem. [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6a38/1).